# URL building with Flask and non-unique handler names

Tags: python, url, url-routing, wsgi, flask

Flask provides a [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#url-building) function to generate URLs to handlers based on the URL pattern. But this would imply that the handler functions must have unique names across the entire application. Is that correct?

**Example**

Module A has a handler `index`:

```
@app.route('/')
def index(): pass
```

And Module B has another handler `index`:

```
@app.route('/anotherindex')
def index(): pass
```

How to distinguish the handlers called `index` when building URLs?

```
url_for('index')
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I don't know how you could do with all the views routed by the same module.

What I usually do is separate my views in different modules (like you did with module `A` and `B`), and register them as blueprints, after that, when using the `url_for()` function, you can prefix the view name with your blueprint name and then avoid conflicts and potential problems.

Here is an example:

**main_views.py:**

```
from flask import Blueprint
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route('/')
def index():
    pass
```

**admin_views.py:**

```
from flask import Blueprint
admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__)

@admin.route('/admin')
def index():
    pass
```

**application.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from main_views import main
from admin_views import admin

app = Flask('my_application')
app.register_blueprint(main)
app.register_blueprint(admin)
```

Now, to access the 2 index views and still distinguish one from the other, just use `url_for('main.index')` or `url_for('admin.index')`

### EDIT:

Just one more useful details about routing using blueprints, when registering the blueprint, you can pass a `url_prefix` argument, that will apply to every view within this blueprint.

For example, given the following code:

**admin_views.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint
admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__)

@admin.route('/')
def index():
    pass

@admin.route('/logout')
def logout():
    pass
```

**application.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from admin_views import admin

app = Flask('my_application')
app.register_blueprint(admin, url_prefix='/admin')
```

The 2 views would be available at the URL `/admin/` and `/admin/logout`

Comment: +1 for an excellent answer (now, I just need to find the +2 button).

Comment: thanks for the great answer, it really helped me. I'm not sure if it changed, but it seems it's "url_prefix" and not just "prefix".

Comment: A simple example on Blueprints.  This worked very well with my project.  Upvote to you.