# Using flask/blueprint for some static pages

Tags: python, flask

So I am just a little confused on how to build pages with flask without having to state each view.

How would I make a blue print that would pickup on the pages i want to load?

say these are my example pages

```
templates/
   layout.html
   section1/
     subsection/index.html
     subsection2/index.html
   section2
     subsection/index.html
       childofsubsection/index.html
```

I would liked to assume if i went to example.com/section1/subsection/ it would know to look for its corresponding page without having to specifically stating it. The documentation http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/ gets very close to explaining this, but i am still a little lost.

```
from flask import Flask
from yourapplication.simple_page import simple_page

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(simple_page)
```

also, not sure where this was supposed to go? this looks like it would go in the application.py, but asks to import from "yourapplication"

Very new to flask and not a python expert either. Really just need some dumbing down :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you'd like to see an example of `Blueprint` usage, you can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957396/url-building-with-flask-and-non-unique-handler-names/6958518#6958518).

About the "template auto-find" part of your question: like the documentation explains, blueprints allows to specify a folder where static files and/or templates will be looked for, this way you don't have to specify the full path to the template file in your `render_template()` call, but only the file name.

If you wanted your views to "magically" know which file they should pick, you have to do a bit of hack. A solution, for example, could be to apply a decorator on your view that would make it pick the template file based on the function name, such a decorator would look like this:

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import render_template

def autorender(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        context = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return render_template('%s.html' % func.func_name, **context)
    return wrapper
```

Then you would just have to return the context in your view as a dict (or an empty dict if there is no context):

```
@my_blueprint.route('/')
@autorender
def index():
    return {'name': 'John'} # or whatever your context is
```

And it would automatically pick the template named `index.html`.