# Flask views in separate module

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

flaskr.py

```
# flaskr.py    
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

import views


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

views.py

```
# views.py
from flaskr import app
from flask import render_template, g

@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    entries = None
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)
```

python3 flaskr.py

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working but if i move the whole app into a separate package it works flawless.

No errors, not nothing except a 404 like the views.py is ignored.
I'm knew to Flask and i'm trying out different things to understand how it actually works.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried  `from views import *` in `flaskr.py`?

Comment: My guess is that `views` is being looked up everywhere except in the current directory.  Change `import views` to `import .views` (not the leading `.` in `views`) and see if that works.

Comment: @SiddharthaRT if i change it to that i get "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: show_entries.html"

Comment: @SeanVieira that doesn't work at all. The module is being loaded when i'm using "import views" but i guess it is loaded into a different context.

Comment: Turns out I was wrong: Refer to Lukas's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this has to do with `app.root_path`.

- In *views.py*, `app.root_path` is `/path/to/project/flaskr`
- But in *flaskr.py*, `app.root_path` is `/path/to/project`

So Flask expects *views.py* to be put into a package.

Comment: Can someone elaborate a bit more on this answer?  It sounds like the importing in at least one of the files only works correctly when it is in a package.  But how can that be?  The relative position of the files is the same in either case  so why would the path change?

Answer (score 14):

If you want to **move views** to **other file** you need to **register [blueprint](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/)**:

flask.py

```
# flaskr.py    
from flask import Flask
from .views import my_view

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(my_view)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

views.py

```
# views.py
from flaskr import app
from flask import render_template, g

my_view = Blueprint('my_view', __name__)

@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    entries = None
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)
```

***Similar questions:***

- [URL building with Flask and non-unique handler names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957396/url-building-with-flask-and-non-unique-handler-names/6958518)
- [Using flask/blueprint for some static pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054099/using-flask-blueprint-for-some-static-pages)

Comment: There is a cycle import in your example, isn't there?

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'my_view' from partially initialized module 'views' (most likely due to a circular import)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue for me by adding a wilcard in flaskr.py. I saw this idea first at https://github.com/jennielees/flask-sqlalchemy-example, however I am now trying to do a blueprint as it is better to maintain the code in the long run I believe.

flaskr.py

```
# flaskr.py    
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# import views
from views import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

views.py

```
# views.py
from flaskr import app
from flask import render_template, g

@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    entries = None
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)
```

Comment: With this approach, it's important to import the views after creating `app`.

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.1.x, there is the [`add_url_rule()` method where the views are loaded lazily from a separate module](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/lazyloading/?highlight=views) by placing view functions *undecorated*  in a separate module, say `views.py`, and in the app file, one calls it as `views.app.add_url_rule(path, view_func=views.view_func)` in the same way as when we placed the route decorators above their view functions in the same file.

[I'd also like to add this post as a resource](https://pythonise.com/series/learning-flask/application-factory-pattern-%7C-learning-flask-ep.-30)